# Trying to upload to firebase storage with react. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ref')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, storage, typeerror

Here is the below code. The console log tells me that it's correctly reading the image, but firebase.storage is undefined for some reason.

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/storage";

function ProfilePic() {


    const [image , setImage] = React.useState('');

    const upload = ()=>{
    if (image == null) return;
        console.log(image);
        const ref = firebase.storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`);
        ref.put(image).on("state_changed" , alert("success") , alert);
        
    }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <center>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e)=>{setImage(e.target.files[0])}}/>
      <button onClick={upload}>Upload</button>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProfilePic;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the legacy namespaced library to use it how you are expecting.

```
import "firebase/compat/storage";
```

By using `"firebase/storage"`, you end up importing the modern modular SDK instead.

You also need to use call `firebase.storage()` to get its instance rather than the namespace:

```
const ref = firebase.storage().ref(`images/${image.name}`);
```

Comment: then I get the error:
TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.storage.ref is not a function

Comment: @Kris See update.